# prepared statement with unknow arguments

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a function in which I can connect to a database and select some results. I want to do that with a prepared statement, but without knowing what type of arguments are given.

Lets say this is my test data

```
int id = 5;
String name = "John Doe";
```

then I want to call my function like this:

```
read("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", id);
```

or

```
read("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND name=?",id,name);
```

As shown there is one or more argument which I get as input, but when I have to set it to a questionmark I get stuck because I have to say if it is a `String`(`setString`) or `int`(`setInt`).

How can I solve this problem without knowing what the variable is? (line 9)

```
1 public void read(String query, String... args){
2   try{
3       
4       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, username, password);
5       
6       PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
7       for(int i = 0; i < args.length;i++){
8           //What do I put here?
9           pstmt.setValue(i,args[i]);
10      }


        String select = "use datapersistentie;";
        pstmt.executeQuery(select);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query); 

        while (rs.next()) {   
          // do something with the result
        }

        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to do this yourself. The problem has been solved many times, for example by Spring Framework's `JdbcTemplate` class.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the tip, but I just started to connect to a database using java so I am not directly going for spring. I want to learn and understand the basics of `JDBC` first. so I better use a normal statement for now?

Comment: Then don't create a generic method like that. Instead write a method called `getUserById(int id)` and `getUserByIdAndName(int id, String name)`. Although id sounds like a primary key, which makes it unique, so it doesn't make sense to do a select with both an id and a name. Maybe `getUsersByName(String name)`?

Comment: It was more that had one function for all my communication with the database. If I have to make a seperate function for all of the different tables the file is getting a lot bigger

Comment: Yes, you will end up writing a lot more code (and a lot of boilerplate), but the design will be more robust. It's your choice: be lazy and have poor design or type out more code and have a good well defined interface to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending in String arguments, you can just change line 9 to `setString(i+1,args[i])`

You could also use an Object... argument and call setObject(i+1,args[i]) if you know the types where you are calling it.

Comment: but if I have a datetime I can still use `setString` if I format it correctly?

Comment: that depends on the database JDBC driver.  Some will let you.  If you change to the Object... version, you'd just pass a java.sql.Timestamp() as an argument in the right place.